# Set Theory, Infinite chain of subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Given an infinite chain of subsets $S_1\subseteq S_2 \subseteq S_3...$. Consider a subset $N\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} S_{i}$, can we say that $N\subseteq S_i$ for some $i$. If so, how do we prove this?

Comment: A counter-example: let $S_i = (-\infty; i)$ and let $N = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot say that. Example: $S_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $N=\mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: But in this case, N is not a proper subset of the union

Comment: @uptoisomorphism OK, then take $N=\{2,3,4,5,...\}$.

Comment: @uptoisomorphism The notation you have used for proper subset is not very standard. That is why I didn't make $N$  proper subset. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thank you

Comment: @uptoisomorphism or make $N$ the even positive integers, e.g, or really any infinite subset of $\Bbb N$.